# Ограничить подключение к бд

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

(web-приложение) Есть задача: записать в бд информацию, но при этом это может делать только 1 человек. Вроде как можно использовать синглтон, но ставить ограничения на чтение из бд нельзя. Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

```
private static Singleton instance;
private static boolean isLock = false;

public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
    if(!isLock) {
        lock();
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}
private static void lock(){
    isLock = true;
}
public static void anLock(Singleton inst){
    isLock = false;
}
```

Так сработает?(получаем экземпляр, как с ним наработались, возвращаем его и он разрешает работать дальше)

Comment: Делайте через обычный лок/synchronized, получен запрос на запись - получение лока - произведение записи - отпуск лока.

Comment: не совсем понятно, вы когда конектитесь к базе, вы же прописываете и логин и пароль. - это один человек. А если через веб, то сделайте ему авторизацию личную.

Comment: @Etki посмотрите, так должно работать?И получается что для чтения использовать нужно другой коннекшн?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SpecificEntityManager {

    private final ReadWriteLock lock;

    public SpecificEntityManager(ReadWriteLock lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public void performWrite(DataTransferObject input) {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            // ...
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Что здесь происходит:

- Есть некоторый инстанс лока `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock`, который обеспечивает синхронизацию приложения. ReadWriteLock - это просто два лока, которые позволяют читать неограниченному количеству потребителей, а писать - только одному. В один момент может производиться только чтение или запись; вообще по заданию требуется ограничить только запись (для этого было бы достаточно простого лока), но в данном примере я на всякий захватил и чтение.
- Указанный лок передается произвольному менеджеру сущностей в конструкторе. Это позволит использовать тот же ок еще где-то, если запись блокируется не только в одном месте.
- Все, что идет после получения лока, оборачивается в `try ... finally`. Так вы спасете свое приложение, если, скажем, в 10% случаев оно отрабатывает этот участок кода с ошибкой (остальные 90% случаев продолжат благополучно работать). Если не использовать аналогичные конструкции, то есть вероятность получить навсегда залоченное приложение.
- Если вам нужно блокировать не всю запись целиком, а только для конкретной сущности, лучшим решением будет использовать решение StripedLock с относительно большим пулом. StripedLock - это некоторый пул локов, которые выдаются по хеш-коду объекта, для которого запрашивается лок; таким образом можно поддерживать в памяти относительно небольшой пул локов, которые де-факто относятся сразу к многим сущностям, но которые в большинстве случае позволят обеспечить синхронный доступ к разным сущностям, "не задевая" друг друга. Имплементация StripedLock есть, например, в библиотеке Guava от google.